# undefined method `location' for #<ActionController::CgiRequest

Tags: ruby, rails-geocoder

Im using geocoder gem and im getting the below error

```
undefined method `location' for #<ActionController::CgiRequest
```

i have required the gem in controller:

```
require 'geocoder'
```

and used

```
request.location.inspect
```

can anyone help me!

Comment: try `Geocoder::Request.location`

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding this dependency? It's not clear from the documentation if that applies to Rails or just regular Rack apps.

Comment: @tadman yes i did

Comment: Are you using a supported version of Rails? It's not clear what you're doing wrong here, but it looks like the extension didn't load in properly. That `require` call shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: yes..im using Rails 3.2.13 and i have installed older version of gem because to support my older ruby version(1.8.7)

Comment: @marmeladze: i get uninitialized constant error. i have identified the error. this is because of unsupported version of gem. and this link https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/537 helps me to fix further issues. thanks :)